# Stop the cursor overlapping the value when using replace

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am wondering how to prevent the behavior of overlapping the value when i place the cursor in the middle of the value. After, i am trying to replace the double space with one space instead but it overlap my text value while replace double space to single space.

here's the example of code. any suggestion i can prevent this kind of behavior?

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#txtInput").keyup(
     function(event) {
     
       var position = event.target.selectionStart;
       event.target.value = event.target.value.replace(/  +/g, ' ');
       event.target.selectionEnd = position;
     
   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="txtInput" type="text" value=""/>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "overlapping my text value while replace" -using your snippet, I can't see any sort of "overlapping" behavior. It simply removes forces you to conform to a single space.

Comment: when you are doing double spacing, it'll overlap the first character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only replace the value and set the selection position if the value is changing, then set *both* the start and the end of the selection, and set it *back* by one character.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#txtInput").keyup(
     function(event) {
     
       var position = event.target.selectionStart;
       var replacement = event.target.value.replace(/  +/g, ' ');
       if (replacement !== event.target.value) {
           event.target.value = replacement;
           event.target.selectionStart = event.target.selectionEnd = position-1;
       }
     
   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="txtInput" type="text" value=""/>
```

Answer (score 4):

You could check if you actually modify the length of the string, if you do you need to subtract 1 from the position.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#txtInput").keyup(
     function(event) {
       var len = event.target.value.length;
       var position = event.target.selectionStart;
       event.target.value = event.target.value.replace(/  +/g, ' ');
       if (len !== event.target.value.length) --position;
       event.target.selectionEnd = position;
     
   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="txtInput" type="text" value=""/>
```